# Firewall on a Wireless Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall

Firewall on a Wireless NetworkI currently have a WiFi network with a very simple operation, the client computers (five desktops e two smartphones) connect directly to the router (tp-link), which connects to our internet provider's modem.

But I now need to have more secure access control on this network, for example:

- Block websites
- Block email services (only allow for those who need it)
- Block OneDrive, Google Drive, iCloud, etc.
- Block FTP, SFTP (SFTP only for one person allowed)
- Block transmission of local files to websites (uploads)
- Block unauthorized devices from using the network (wifi or wired)

As I have no experience in network management, my question is as follows.

Can I apply a firewall to directly monitor the router and apply the filters or do I need a physical machine on my network through which all this communication will pass and it will carry out data verification and the blocking any unauthorized action?

Comment: You need to make the jump into advanced firewall and routing. Best way to start is to read up on pfsense. This software turns an old PC, with the addition of some network cards and squid software - into a router that can do most/all of what you may require.

Comment: agree with the above, but third party firmware may also be an option for your router to gain the functionality you crave. both openwrt and dd-wrt are usually options depending on the model number of your tp-link

Comment: And if I use a hardware solution with pfSense (eg.: netgate) between the modem and the Access Point (router), might it work for what I need?

Comment: Yes, either option would work for what you want.